# If I buy Windows 11 Pro "English edition", can I change language to my local one at will (or at least at installation)?

Tags: windows-11

I guess I can understand why Microsoft sold language-specific editions of Windows in the past, when it was distributed on floppy disks, but since the standardization of CD-ROM and later storage media/distribution mechanisms, it makes no technical sense.

Is it the case with Windows 11? That is, if I buy the English version of Windows 11 Pro, is that fixed to English, or can I change it to my local language when installing it (or maybe even while running)? The reasons I don't want to buy the local edition is:

1. If it cannot be set/switched to English, support becomes WAY more difficult since it's impossible to get hold of anyone speaking my language. Me taking screenshots of menus and whatnot will make no sense to somebody speaking English (which is the only feasible support language online).
2. It is slightly more expensive for some reason. Possibly due to physical scarcity.

Comment: You can change your the default system language to whatever you want. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-system-language-windows-10

Comment: Only Single Language editions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 DO NOT have the compatibility to change which language packs are installed.  Windows 10 Professional Single Language DOES NOT exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the language during the installation or even later on in the Settings App under `Time & language -> Language & Region`